# Visual Studio Code .NET Core .csproj exclude

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, csproj

I have a .NET Core project using Visual Studio **Code** looks like

```
Angular2CLIApp
wwwroot
myproject.csproj
```

The Angular 2 CLI app has a depenedency on the selenium-webdriver which once installed places a Page.aspx.cs (+ some) file into the node_modules folder in the Angular2CLIApp folder - this is causing the myproject.csproj build to fail

I am trying to exclude the Angular2CLIApp folder from the build using item groups in the .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Angular2CLIApp/" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have found I can resolve this a bit by changing the project structure to something like

```
SPAs
    Angular2CLIApp
DOTNET
   wwwroot
   myproject.csproj
```

But this is not really ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after much trial and error, this seems to work

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <DefaultItemExcludes>
    $(DefaultItemExcludes);Angular2CLIApp/**;
  </DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `Include` it's `Remove` like so...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Angular2CLIApp/" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Easiest, most straightforward solution. While absolutely correct, the accepted answer is a bit esoteric.